# Sending an email from Pylons

Tags: python, pylons

I am using Pylons to develop an application and I want my controller actions to send emails to certain addresses.  Is there a built in Pylons feature for sending email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is [turbomail](http://www.python-turbomail.org/). In documentation you have an entry where is explains how to integrate it with Pylons.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use standard Python library modules, `email` to prepare the mail and `smtp` to send it? What extra value beyond that are you looking for from the "built-in feature"?

Comment: Handling non-ASCII data transparently was the thing I missed most.  I haven't checked lately whether Python 2.6 improves this or not.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jjinux.blogspot.com/2009/02/python-logging-to-email-in-pylons.html